# External mouse - Have to do double click to make a single click

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, touchpad, dell-inspiron

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and a Dell Optical Mouse. Here are the problems whenever I connect the external mouse, which started from yesterday:

1. Left button works as right button. Right button works as it is.
2. I have to double click to make a single click. This usually works with the right button. Sometimes with the left button.
3. As soon as I plug in the mouse, it behaves as if the right button has been pressed down even though I haven't clicked any of the buttons.
4. My touchpad doesn't work when the mouse is plugged in (it used to work before, although this doesn't bother me much as long as my USB mouse works).
5. Plugged the mouse in all USB ports. Same problems.

Things I have tried:

1. Reinstalling inputattach.
2. Switching primary order of buttons from left to right in Ubuntu's Mouse and Touchpad settings
3. sudo modprobe -r psmouse and then sudo modprobe psmouse
4. xinput --list is able to list my Dell mouse. Ran xinput set-button-map "PixArt Dell MS116 USB Optical Mouse" 3 2 1 & to switch left and right.

The double-click workaround is working now but it's kinda annoying. I would rather prefer my left and right switched if it means I can get back to single clicks.

Thanks!

Comment: Test the mouse with another computer (if no access to another computer then maybe a smart TV or whatever). Test your laptop and OS with another mouse. The chances are you will learn where the problem is. Maybe the mouse is malfunctioning and simply needs to be replaced.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I bought a new mouse and it's working now perfectly! Thankfully it was just old-mouse problems and not my OS playing up :)